# Can I do a quicker recursion for this pascal triangle in java?

Tags: java, debugging, recursion, runtime

```
public static int[] computePT(int k) {

    int[] arr = new int[k];

    if(k==1){
        arr[0] = 1;
        return arr;
    }else{

        for (int i=(k+1)/2 -1 ; i >= 0; i--){

            if(i==0){
                arr[0] = 1;
                arr[k-1] = 1;

            }else {
                int[] yell = computePT(k-1);
                arr[i] = yell[i-1] + yell[i];
                arr[k-i-1] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

This function will return the elements of kth row in a pascal triangle, but I would like to do this in a shorter runtime. It seems that the recursion is not fast enough...

Comment: could you quantify "shorter runtime"?

Comment: For a large input k, such as 20, the runtime takes about 7 sec. Can do it in 5 secs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compute

```
            int[] yell = computePT(k-1);
```

int the loop. Moving it before the loop should make a better performance